# Intersection of the stable and unstable manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Been studying differential equations and this question popped up :

> Let $W^S(0)$ and $W^U(0)$ be the stable and unstable manifolds defined in $B=B_r(0)$ for a vector field $F\in C^1(B)$, such that $B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, with an equilibrium point in the origin. Then for sufficiently small $r$ we have that $W^S(0)\cap W^U(0)=\{0\}$.

Now I still haven't managed to prove this but there is something that's annoying me which this that all the examples of the theorem that I have seen we have that $W^S(0)\cap W^U(0)=\{0\}$, so I wonder if anyone knows of an example where this intersection will be different that $\{0\}$?

New edit : As mentioned in the comments I know now an example of this. Does anyone have anyone how to pove the statement tough ? What stops us from having an inifinite number of homoclinic orbits with radius arbritary small ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a homoclinic orbit.

Comment: Oh yeah I just found an example Thanks. Do you have any advice for proving the statement about $r$? @user10354138